# Ubuntu 14.04 crossover connection cannot ping

Tags: networking, wired

I am trying to connect two ubuntu 14.04 pc to each other by using crossover cable. 
From network settings i gave IP addresses as ;(Ipv4 manual)
PC1 - IP:10.0.0.1 Network Mask:255.255.255.0
PC2 - IP:10.0.0.2 Network Mask:255.255.255.0

PC1 is the server and it has apache installed. It serves pages from localhost. I wanted to see this web page from PC2 browser by typing IP1. However, my problem is starting from the beginning which I cannot even ping from PC1 to PC2 or vice versa.

results of "ifconfig"

PC1: 
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:a8:f0:5e:91:94

```
      inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::42a8:f0ff:fe5e:9194/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:38 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:246 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:7569 (7.5 KB)  TX bytes:39911 (39.9 KB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:ec200000-ec220000
```

lo

```
      Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:933 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:933 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:74985 (74.9 KB)  TX bytes:74985 (74.9 KB)
```

PC2:
eth2

```
      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:a8:f0:5e:92:48 
      inet addr:10.42.0.40  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::42a8:f0ff:fe5e:9194/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:467 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:460 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:64183 (64.1 KB)  TX bytes:54663 (54.6 KB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:ec200000-ec220000
```

lo

```
      Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:1380 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1380 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:103299 (103.2 KB)  TX bytes:103299 (103.2 KB)
```

`iptables --list`

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:mdns reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             PKTTYPE = broadcast
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             PKTTYPE = multicast
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID LOG level warning prefix " Invalid "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 25/min burst 7 LOG level info prefix "#BANNED-BY-ROOT# "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Server has extra:
Chain Input
    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
Chain Forward
    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.42.0.0./24        state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    ACCEPT     all  --  10.42.0.0./24        anywhere
    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere 
    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Comment: How are you configuring the IP addresses?

Comment: I tried two options ,
1. From edit connection and then IPV4  and i am selection manual for both
2. ifconfig eth0 192.168.5.1 from command line

Comment: I mean with the `network-manager` (if yes, with the applet or with its configuration files), with `/etc/network/interfaces`, etc.

Comment: For /etc/network/interfaces, i dont know how to do

Comment: @mchid I am trying this in a university lab so to connect the normal system, Wpa-supplicant installed for all computer. (I have no idea what it is.)

Comment: and also output of my /etc/network/interfaces ,
`code`
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback `code`

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/368841/how-to-get-add-apache2-to-iptables

Comment: sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

Comment: or at least sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

Comment: I don't see anything for ufw here? is it installed?

Comment: for ubuntu 14.04 it was disabled as default , most probably that is why but yeah it is installed

Comment: for these 3 iptables where should i write them on server or both server and client ?

Comment: because you don't have any iptables rules for ufw, you also have drop all rules set which usually are done manually as far as I know and to disable iptables in ubuntu the standard method is to disable ufw and ufw disables iptables but if ufw is not installed then it won't very well disable iptables

Comment: probably both . or use ufw instead (recommended)

Comment: I tried `code`sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT `code` for both. Did not work but what i found that server has more rules. Also i did not get what u mean by use ufw. U mean not disable ?

Comment: set allow rules using ufw and still keep it disabled at first and then try enabling it to see if every thing works fine with the rules set to allow incoming and outgoing for the ports that your server or your services run on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, start over.

Insert the ethernet cable to both computers and on the server computer, click on network manager icon on your dash and select "edit connections".

Select auto eth0 and select ipv4 tab and then select connection-type "shared to other computers". Save changes and exit the menu.

Then, click on network manager and then click on the network auto eth0 to refresh the network or alternatively, run the following command:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

To obtain the ip of the server computer, click on network-manager and select "connection-information" to obtain the ip. Use this ip to access the server from pc2.

---

allow firewall access:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

and to allow ssh if you want that as well:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

[more info][1] [1]: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-iptables-on-ubuntu-14-04

---

To use ufw instead:

I tried this earlier today on a fresh install with ufw disabled. Set allow rules using ufw.

```
sudo ufw allow in 80/tcp
sudo ufw allow out 80/tcp
```

You can also set for udp but not needed here, this is just an example:

```
sudo ufw allow out 80/udp
sudo ufw allow in 80/udp
```

If you want ssh access:

```
sudo ufw allow out 22/tcp
sudo ufw allow in 22/tcp
```

Comment: Nope, again did not work. They took the ip but it is not returning a response for ping

Comment: @Abendstern and dont forget to disable ufw and gufw because you need incoming and outgoing open not just outgoing

Comment: I did the what u explained and server gave the IP address to client . I post the result of ifconfig to explain better :)

Comment: for gufw, both PC says command command not found

Comment: ufw, I have done already at the beginning

Comment: I did not need ufw, I updated the iptables as @mchid mentioned from /etc/local/iptables.sh and also ı changed the hostname of computers as they were same for all the lab. After that I reboot the both client and server. Thanks mchid

Answer (score 0):

Use an address of the `192.168.0.0/16` subnet, not `10.0.0.0/24`, e.g. assign PC1 `192.168.5.1` and PC2 `192.168.5.2`. `10.0.0.0/24` addresses might not leave the PCs because they're not routed.

Comment: Thanks for addresses. I want to ask one more thing to be on the safe side. There can be anything extra then address or not ? I mean to setup crossover connection i am just following the steps that i mentioned and plus i am  disabling firewall (sudo ufw disable).

Comment: Did you try what I wrote or are you asking before trying it? Setting the addresses is sufficient.

Comment: I tried and it is not working same thing, I ping the other one and it just says nothing